# Unique partial composite primary key in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm guessing the answer is no, but... is it possible to enforce uniqueness on only part of a composite primary key?

```
create table foo (
  id integer,
  yesno boolean,
  extra text,
  primary key (id, yesno, extra)
)
```

The idea here is that I want `id` + `yesno` to be unique for this particular table, but I want to include `extra` in the index so I can take advantage of [Postgres index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-index-only-scans.html).

Yes, I could create a second, unique index on `id` + `yesno`, but that would be wasteful.

Comment: A primary key can't be "partial" by definition

Comment: Primary keys are a combination of `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` by default. An index on a `TEXT` field seems "heavy" anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [INCLUDE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createindex.html) option to add extra columns in the index that are not actually part of the index itself.

```
create table foo (
  id integer not null,
  yesno boolean not null,
  extra text
);
Create unique index foo_uk 
           on foo (id, yesno) 
      include (extra);
```

You did not indicate what Postgres version you have, so this may not be appropriate, as you need at least version 11.

Comment: The only drawback of this solution is that this "primary key" cannot be referenced by foreign keys.

Comment: True.  but if reference needed, I would probably have added a surrogate as PK  rather than propagate  the original multiple column PK.  That would certainly be the option with this solution.